# Determining Reshus Harabbim if a street is not busy on Shabbos

Tags: halacha, shabbat, eruv-chatzerot, maseches-eruvin

If a street has 600,000 people travelling on it during the week, but on weekends it does not since people aren't working, is it considered a Reshus Harabbim? Do we say that just because there are 600,000 people travelling on it during the work week it retains its status as a Reshus Harabbim even thought there aren't 600,000 people travelling on it on Shabbos?

What about the opposite- if there are only 600,000 people travelling on it on Shabbos but most days there aren't 600,000 people travelling on it? Do we go by Shabbos or the majority of days?

(I know that this question is only relevant according to the opinions that 600,000 people travelling in it is a necessity in order to be a Reshus Harabbim. The question is predicated on that assumption.)